# How to delete multiple rows in Kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid with first column as Checkboxes. I want to delete multiple rows using those check boxes. I am able to delete only single row at a time.

I tried adding

```
.Batch(true)
```

for the data source and below is my function for delete button outside the grid.

```
function deleteRule() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.select().each(function () {
        grid.removeRow($(this));
    });
}
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Do you necessarily have to use a checkbox to select the rows you want to delete? Why don't you just make your grid select multiple rows then each time a row is selected, you keep each row/record (uid) in an Array. Then onClick of your Delete button, loop through the gridDataSource and use the "remove" [gridDataSource.remove(selectedRow);] method then "sync" [gridDataSource.sync();] it.

Answer (score 3):

Yo mate,

How exactly do you remove that one row? Why you use the select method?

Basically I would suggest you to create a delete button which executes the logic to delete the selected rows - I guess you are using a tempalte column with a checkbox inside. If you add a class to that checkbox you can easily select all the checkboxes inside of the grid. So lets say the name of the class for the checkbox is **cool** then you can execute the following logic in the delete button click handler:

```
function whenYourDeleteButtonIsClicked(){
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $('.cool:selected').each(function(){
       grid.removeRow($(this).closest('tr'));
    })
}
```

I hope you got the idea mate.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . This is how my first column looks after modification. Is this correct ?                       columns.Bound(p => p.checkBox).ClientTemplate("<input type=checkbox' class= 'checkboxcls' />").Title("");           and here goes my function               function deleteRule() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $('.checkboxcls:selected').each(function () {
        grid.removeRow($(this).closest('tr'));
    })
}          Nothing works now :(  pls help. I'm very new to all these stuff.

Comment: not sure what is wrong - send some small project somehow so I can take a look

Comment: In order to retrieve the lines, I will have rather use `$("#grid").find("input:checked")`, but I think it is about the same as your solution...

Comment: so why is grid databound called for each row after each single row remove? i process each grid row on databound and after removing them, databound is called for each row and the row still thinks the removed row is there so i just get a lot of js errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i use

works very well

```
    $('#your-grid-id').data("kendoGrid").select().each(function () {
        grid.dataSource.remove(grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr")));
   });
```

Comment: This may have worked in the past. Now the latest 2018 Kendo throws an error: TypeError: grid.dataSource is undefined

Comment: you must have a variable already referenced to grid like `var grid = $('#your-grid-id').data("kendoGrid")`

Comment: You're right. My blind eyes couldn't see that I did not capitalize the "S" in "dataSource". var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); grid.dataSource.read();